Which question should be featured in an article about BSE's tenth anniversary?
Bitcoin Stack Exchange is turning ten. The Stack Exchange team is going to write an article about our site and a few others that are celebrating anniversaries. They asked us to suggest topics from our site that would be noteworthy, outstanding, or representative to share in the article.
Please suggest a single topic per post and include a couple sentences of explanation or motivation why the topic is a good representative for our work here. Topics can either be sourced from the main site or the meta site.

I'm going to take the top three in the answers and feature those!

One of the first Qs that comes to mind is: Will there be 21 million bitcoins eventually?
The question is easy to grasp even for the layman, and Pieter's answer is both interesting and instructive. Additionally, the hard-money/21-million meme is very strong in 'bitcoin culture' these days, so I think it is quite relevant.

I think this question could be a good contender. The lightning network is a very exciting part of bitcoin development imo, but mainstream knowledge of it is almost nonexistent! A relatively simple explanation of what it is and how it works could be very helpful to a lot of new users.
How does the Lightning network work in simple terms?

How to securely store bitcoin is always a relevant question, no matter if you're a complete newbie, or a longtime hodler. Not having your coins taken from you is of course a primary concern, so maybe this question will catch interest and pull some eyes in:
How can government "seize" bitcoins?

Pontificating about the supposed advantages of a proof of stake system is quite trendy these days, so another good candidate might be this question.
Why doesn't Bitcoin migrate to proof-of-stake?

This question is maybe a little less accessible to newbies with minimal knowledge about the bitcoin protocol, but any sort of attack will probably be exciting and interesting to read about, so perhaps it is still a decent candidate.
What is time warp attack and how does it work in general?

This question does a good job of grounding what can otherwise be esoteric discussions about mining/security into a more relatable context. Disclaimer: I wrote the top rated answer on this one.
How does proof of work inspire trust when the work is just guessing?
